# How can I make reverse function of diff of Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have some kind of arrays numbers like this a= 1 4 2 5 3...
So I just use for diff function in matlab.
     Diff= diff(a); 
Then I can be got some diff results as well.
But I want to know also integral function as above.

```
 For example,
 a= 1 4 2 5 3 ...
 Integral(a)= 1 5 7 12 15...
```

Is there any function as above it in Matlab?

Comment: @Divakar I disagree. Just because the answer is `cumsum` it is not a duplicate question. And it's actually not even entirely true.

Comment: @thewaywewalk You were right, that wasn't a close one, but found another one, which is an exact copy of it. I can't close it as a duplicate of it, but hopefully someone else could re-close this with the linked question.

Comment: And actually: no, there is no inverse to the diff function, it can not exist, since diff discards information.